# jQuery scroll a div up and down using two buttons

Tags: jquery

I have a simple set of two buttons that when hovered should make a div move up and down to simulate a scrolling effect:

```
$("#down").hover(function () {

    $('.scroll').animate({ "marginTop": "-=50px" }, "fast");

});

$("#up").hover(function () {

    $('.scroll').animate({ "marginTop": "+=50px" }, "fast");

});
```

However I have two issues:

1.) I need it to stop when it gets to the end and then hide the button so they know they've reached the end

2.) It needs to scroll continually when the user has their mouse over, currently it does it just once on mouse over and then runs it again on mouse leave.

3.) If the content does not exceed the parent element height then hide both buttons as we don't need to scroll it.

Can anyone help?

I was thinking that perhaps 1 could be solved by finding out the height of the scroll panel and judging its offset to its parent element that holds it and creates the framed view?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code still need some debugging, but you can get the idea in it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($('.content').height() > $('.container').height()) {
        $("#down").hover(function () {
            animateContent("down");
        }, function() { $('.content').stop(); });

        $("#up").hover(function () {
            animateContent("up");
        }, function() { $('.content').stop(); });
    }
});

function animateContent(direction) {  
    var animationOffset = $('.container').height() - $('.content').height();
    if (direction == 'up') {
        animationOffset = 0;
    }

    $('.content').animate({ "marginTop": animationOffset + "px" }, "fast");
}
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/a89DF/6/

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll need to set the animations parameter to the divs actual height [jQuery .height() method](http://api.jquery.com/height/)
2. You should change your [mouse events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) bindings on "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" and then with "mouseleave" you can stop a jQuery element animation with the [jQuery .stop() method](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)
3. You can calculate this with the [jQuery .height() method](http://api.jquery.com/height/) too.

Answer (score 0):

I think `animate` is more useful for single animation effects rather than a continuous and variable change. You can implement this yourself with an interval.

```
var interval;

$("#down").mouseenter(function () {
    interval = setInterval(ScrollDown, 100);
});

$("#down").mouseleave(function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
});

function ScrollDown() {
    $('.scroll').css("marginTop", "+=50px");
    // check bounds here to solve problem #1
}

/* do the same stuff for scrolling up */
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written the jQuery plugin `jquery.scrollbuttons` which should fit your needs. It has a [page on github](https://github.com/philippze/jquery.scrollbuttons) and an [examples page](http://jquery.scrollbuttons.bruneck-berlin.com/).

The only thing the plugin will not do is to hide the button when scrolling is finished. If you still need this feature, I can easily add it.