# vertical autoscroll on mouseover - like deviantart.com "Project giveaway" has

Tags: javascript

http://www.deviantart.com/ is vertically scrolling the content of one of their container upwards when you move your cursor over it. and on mouseleave, it scrolling back down.

You can see it in action on their main page - right now at least - in a container with the text "Project Giveaway: 100 point giveaway #4". I'm wondring how they do this?

Found this line of code trough firebug:
`onmouseout="if (window.LitBox) LitBox.out(this)" onmouseover="if (window.LitBox) LitBox.hover(this, true)"`.
So I tried to google for "LitBox" - but didn't get any luck. All I found was lightbox and listbox...

The exact effect is what I'm looking for.

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('.content').height() > $('.container').height()) {
        $(".content").hover(function () {
            animateContent("down");
        }, function () {
            animateContent("up");
        });
    }
});

    function animateContent(direction) {
        var animationOffset = $('.container').height() - $('.content').height();
        var speed = "slow";
        if (direction == 'up') {
            animationOffset = 0;
            speed = "fast";
        }
        $('.content').animate({
            "marginTop": animationOffset + "px"
        }, speed);
    }
```

[See in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8XBG/)

[my code based on this code :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329035/jquery-scroll-a-div-up-and-down-using-two-buttons/8329376#8329376)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. it's really not that difficult to implement with jquery or css3. With jquery, on mouseover you start running a function to scroll the div up, using animate() perhaps. Then on mouseleave you stop the animation and run another animation to scroll it back.

With css 3, you can achieve it with transitions.
You can check out http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp.