# Scroll multiple divs up and down with 2 buttons

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, scrollable

I have 2 columns that need to be scrollable independently using 2 buttons. I found a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8329376/1628193 that works for 1 column only. So my question is how can I get this to work on at least 2 columns?

Many thanks!

[**See my demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tiaggo/Lhyqascj/2/)

**UPDATED**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="up">Up</a>
<a href="#" id="down">down</a>

<div class="container2">
    <div class="content2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="up2">Up</a>
<a href="#" id="down2">down</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    if ($('.content, .content2').height() > $('.container, .container2').height()) {
        $("#down, #down2").hover(function () {
            animateContent("down");
        }, function() { $('.content, .content2').stop(); });

        $("#up, #up2").hover(function () {
            animateContent("up");
        }, function() { $('.content, .content2').stop(); });
    }
});

function animateContent(direction) {  
    var animationOffset = $('.container, .container2').height() - $('.content, .content2').height();
    if (direction == 'up') {
        animationOffset = 0;
    }

    $('.content, .content2').animate({ "marginTop": animationOffset + "px" }, "fast");
}
```

Comment: Since you're using the same `classes` for both `divs`, there's no way you can have the up and down buttons work for just one of them and not the other. You'd need unique `class` names or `IDs` for each `div` to start.

Comment: Thanks. Just done that (see update) and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Either include your HTML and CSS changes, or update your fiddle to include the changes as well, preferably both. May need to make a new fiddle for that.

Comment: Alright. I've just updated the Fiddle ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/Tiaggo/Lhyqascj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're targeting both of your scrollabe DIVs with your current code.  They have the same class name so you'll either need to give them different IDs or use CSS selectors to specifically target one.  Here's a version that does this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container1 container">
    <div class="content1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="upOne">Up</a>
<a href="#" id="downOne">down</a>

<div class="container2 container">
    <div class="content2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="upTwo">Up</a>
<a href="#" id="downTwo">down</a>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($('.content1').height() > $('.container:first-child').height()) {
        $("#downOne").hover(function () {
            animateContent("down", 1);
        }, function() { $('.content:first-child').stop(); });

        $("#upOne").hover(function () {
            animateContent("up", 1);
        }, function() { $('.content:first-child').stop(); });
    }

    if ($('.content2').height() > $('.container:last-child').height()) {
        $("#downTwo").hover(function () {
            animateContent("down", 2);
        }, function() { $('.content:last-child').stop(); });

        $("#upTwo").hover(function () {
            animateContent("up", 2);
        }, function() { $('.content:last-child').stop(); });
    }

});

function animateContent(direction, index) {  
    var animationOffset = $('.container' + index).height() - $('.content' + index).height();
    if (direction == 'up') {
        animationOffset = 0;
    }

    $('.content' + index).animate({ "marginTop": animationOffset + "px" }, "fast");
}
```

[Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vohadabe/1/edit)

Comment: Great. However when you scroll the second container all the way down the content gets a bigger gap. Plus the containers can have different class names. It doesn't need to be .container:first-child and .container:last-child

Comment: @Tiago I fixed the scroll problem

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a good answer, but here is an alternative :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/christianalfoni/Lhyqascj/3/

I have created a function the takes a wrapper. That way you can add this as many times as you want to different parts of your application, not only these two instances.

```
some code...
```